# Date that will print the last day of the month plus additional 5 days

Tags: php, date, datetime

Hi currently I have a date that is printing the last day of the month for example this month is August, it will print August 31, 2017.

**This is the code:**

```
    $lastdate = date('F t, Y');
    echo $lastdate ;
```

My problem is I want it to print 5 additional days to the last day of the month, so for example rather than it will print August 31, 2017 it will print Septermber 5, 2017

Answer (score 3):

```
echo (new \DateTime('last day of this month'))->modify('+5 days')->format('F j, Y');
```

1. Create a DateTime() object for the end of month
2. Add 5 days to it
3. Format the date

To do next month:

```
echo (new \DateTime('last day of next month'))->modify('+5 days')->format('F j, Y');
```

To do another month:

```
echo (new \DateTime('October 31, 2017'))->modify('+5 days')->format('F j, Y');
```

That should give you the idea.

Comment: Hi I've tried this one applying my code to get end of the month, but it gives me September 30, 2017, 

echo (new \DateTime(date('F t')))->modify('+5 days')->format('F t, Y');

Comment: Why are you using `date('F t')`?

Comment: It is giving me F for the current Month (August), and t for the last day of the month.(31)

Comment: You need to format the date *not* using `t` as it *always* gives you the last day of the month